# Must respond_to :html be specified when only :js is expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 4.2.3. Often times in an action, I expect to do Ajax call, and respond with JS instead (using JS to update certain field), and not expecting it to respond HTML. Example:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Is `format.html` still necessary? I usually just use the following code instead:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @post.save
end
```

And create a `create.js` in view to render it. No problem so far, but is this a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. I do it all the time.. if you are only returning one given type, then why bother with the respond block.  It's just extra boiler plate that in this particular instance serves no purpose

Remember what Einstein said: "Make things as simple as possible, but not simpler."  :)